# Large SQL dataset with hundreds of requests

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Does anybody have an idea of a large sql dataset available free. 
It would be best if it's not dummy generated data, as I would be
firing loads of requests against it.

an example is  http://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/

Answer (score 0):

UCSC database contains the dump of their mysql db : http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/database/

Comment: that looks nice, however it may be very complex for my initial stage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some DNA or Protein Databases, they have plenty of data for free.
http://www.rcsb.org/ for example